# REST API Explore: How to get same list ordered like the search on Foursquare Website?

Tags: api, foursquare

I'm using the REST API (venues platform) to get a list of the top 5 venues per destination and category, like they are listed in the search results on the foursquare website.

For example i do the following request using the explore api endpoint:
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore?near=zurich,CH&query=College %26 University

I'm using the apias a not authenticated. I do not pass a radius, to get the default radius.

Now the results from the api is as follows:
1. ETH Hönggerberg HIL
2. Technopark
3. Kantonsschule Stadelhofen
4. Zürcher Hochschule der Künste, Departement Musik
5. Klubschule Migros

When i search on the Foursquare Website as follow (not logged in!):
https://foursquare.com/explore?near=Zurich%2C%20CH&q=College%20%26%20University

I get the following results listed on the website:
1. SBB Digital
2. Technopark
3. ETH Hönggerberg HIL
4. EF Education First
5. Klubschule Migros

Is it possible to get the same list, as shown on the website (in the same order) also from the api? If yes? how can i do that? how do i call the api or how do i have to sort the results from the api to get the same list?

First i tried to sort the api results by the rating field, but that doesn't do the trick at all. Because in this example no one of the first 30 results does have any rating.

Thank you in advance for your help!
Greets
Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well meanwhile i got the answer from foursquare.
The trick is very simple: just have to add the following parameters to the api call: time=any and day=any.
Then you get the results ordered exactly the same way as on the foursquare webpage (when not authenticated).
Thank you david from foursquare! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are making the explore request with the same user account as on the web. Also, it looks like your queries do not match up exactly. One is "College & University and the other is "college" - try matching up the queries and seeing if the results change.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. well i'm making the request without user account: on the web page i'm not logged in and i'm using the api without authentication. i wanna shop the results independent from any user account. About the query: i am already querying with the same parameters: below the link to the api is not fully shown highlighted. in the API response i see the correct query for college & university.